# Website link is not opening by clicking on href attribue

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am creating a webpage where user click on link, new website will open in new window

**example**

```
echo "<a href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
```

if i click on this link site opens like this in root link (localhost/mysite/www.google.com) instead of www.google.com

Comment: Use `http://sitename.com`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>
```

add `http://` before your link

Answer (score 1):

Protocol agnostic version:

```
<a href='//something/test/and/rest' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>
```

`//` will work as `http://` or `https://` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
```

You must have `http://` or `https://` because without it browser think it as same page with same domain.

So you need to tell browser to send other `http request` rather then adding it in same domain.

Answer (score 0):

To create a link in html that will open in a new window:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

For PHP, echo out the string and use back slashes to escape double quotes (if you're using them instead of single quotes):

```
echo "<a href=\"http://example.com\" target=\"_blank\">Click Me</a>";
```